# Which one is more memory efficient?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm making a minecraft mod and I don't know which one is more recommended.

```
Block[] blocks = new Block[] {BlueBlock, MeatBlock, ....};
for (Block bls : blocks)
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(bls, bls.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
```

or

```
GameRegistry.registerBlock(BlueBlock, "BlueBlock");
GameRegistry.registerBlock(MeatBlock, "MeatBlock");
GameRegistry.registerBlock(..., "...");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is more efficient. The first creates the array, then iterates through the array and registers stuff in it, whilst the second just registers everything, although the performance would be almost unnoticeable as this occurs during the `PRE_INITIALIZATION` stage of Forge loading.

Answer (score 1):

The second one will make less computation, and the first one more automatisation, which is better for laziness. 
In term of memory it shouldn't change much, only blocks will stock some data and should be destroyed afterward, (the garbage collector if so).
Anyway it is a very small difference. But if processing thousands of them the second one will be a bit faster but painful to write.